# Find the "bad control character" that json_decode fails on in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have a lot of JSON strings that are 25-50Kb each. I convert these to arrays with `json_decode()` and it works fine almost every time... But now I have ran into problem, since some of these strings seems to have some bad control character inside.

This is a part of my code that tries to decode the JSON strings to an array:

```
$data_arr = json_decode($json_data, true, 512, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORED);

if (is_null($data_arr)) {
   die(json_last_error_msg()); // --> JSON: Unexpected control character found 
}
```

Now I need to find **which** character that is "unexpected" in order to remove/change that character before I run the `json_decode()`. Is there a way to find the bad character that generates the error?

Comment: Perhaps with some funky regex. PHP's json_* methods won't tell you. Personally I prefer to just dump it into https://jsonlint.com/ or https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Have a look through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52337698/problem-with-json-decode-syntax-error-malformed-json.

Comment: Most probably there is a unescaped NewLine or CarriageReturn symbol. Simply replace them with space.

Answer (score 0):

The bearer token is not properly provided.

kindly recheck whether the word 'Bearer' is mentioned twice.[see here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92zoO.png)